# How to use Powershell to script a domain user's temporary file location

Tags: powershell, deployment, active-directory

I am writing deployment scripts using Powershell to install Scheduled Tasks, Windows Services and IIS App pools. 
Each of these items will be run under the identity of an Active Directory domain user. My issue is that the business rules enforced on the servers state that no process or user can write to the C drive. 
Therefore i need to direct each installed object to use the E drive for temporary storage of any kind.
How can i assign the temp directory environment variable of a domain user using powershell on a server that will have no 'knowledge' of that domain user until i instantiate the installed objects?

When it comes to the IIS app pools I have found a (hacky) solution that could potentially work in this:
https://serverfault.com/questions/711470/applicationpoolidentity-environment-variables-iis

that requires me to set the app pool to run as the profile, fire up the pool,  snoop registry keys, obtain a SID, and then modify registry keys to set the environment variable for the temp drive.

Is there an easier way? And how could i do this for services and scheduled tasks?

Pie in the sky - i write one powershell script to modify the temp env parameter for this one domain account before installing any of these objects and then when they are installed it "just works".

Any suggestions?

Comment: Another thought might be [GPP](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772047(v=ws.11).aspx) using Item Level Targeting?

Comment: Agree ^.  You could even use GPOs to create the scheduled tasks.

Comment: unfortunately, GPO is outside of the realm of our security clearance.